# Not Getting shares but have decent Hashrate

Tags: bitcoind, mining-pool-shares

Just signed up and need help.kinda new to bit mining and am using slushes pool with guiminer and cannot get any accepted shares from my Radeon HD 6870  ,it has Hash rate of 200mh/s and 0 shares after it has ran for a day. I am also mining with my cpu and it is getting around 5mh/s and has gotten over 73 shares,Any help figuring this out would be highly appreciated.

specs: 
Amd driver Catalyst Version 15.7.1
Windows 7 64 bit
Cpu Amd Phenom x6 1045T

Answer (score 0):

What are you mining? If I'm still right old days 200mh/s was enough and 5ms/s also, but today should be already dead not?

It is still possible that pool didn't had luck in solving problem and you got no reward.

I just realised you wrote Slush's pool, which means you mine BTC, which means 
pool has now 36.21Ph/s which is  36,210,000,000,000,000 hashes/sec 
You have 205,000,000 hashes/sec  that means

(36,210,000,000,000,000/100=3,621×10¹⁴=1% ->205000000÷3,621×10¹⁴= 0,000000566%)

You got 0,000000566% of pool mine, if they will mine 100BTC, it will be 0,0000566BTC for you per day... It is still not enough per day to make transaction... Wait a month and let us know here...

With having pool not luck seems not possible since they have written:

Luck 1,7,30days : 128%, 121%, 89%